# Facebook Graph API - Triggering "Edit the info you provide" dialog to reappear

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application allows for user authentication via Facebook. I am calling FB Graph API to get details on a logged in user like so...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<fbUserId>
```

But sometimes I see that email address is not one of the fields which is returned. I think this is because when the user was prompted to allow my app access to their public profile and email address, the user chose not to provide their email address. However my application needs email addresses. Is there any way I can tell FB through the Graph API to make that "Edit the info you provide" dialog to reappear so the user can subsequently choose to give their email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about how to re-prompt users who denied a permission, so that they're asked to grant the already-declined permission?

If so, you can [check which permissions were granted](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#checking) and then re-prompt for those which were previously declined - as you noted, users aren't prompted multiple times to accept a permission if they've already declined it

To re-request, use `auth_type: rerequest` in your call to FB.Login() (javascript) or your call to the Login dialog; I believe the mobile SDKs handle this automatically (e.g. `FBSDKLoginManager` in the IOS SDK)

Note that with your specific example, it's possible a user won't have an email address accessible via the API even if they do grant you the `email` permission, as they may have an unreachable address, be a user without a confirmed address, have signed up to Facebook using a mobile phone number, etc

As a result, you may need to build a UI for users to manually supply their email address anyway, if that info is truly necessary for your app

Comment: thanks for your response, it really helped. It seems my app is logging into FB using this URL https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id= and passing my app's client id as a parameter. Do you know if I can re-request using auth_type rerequest as a parameter to this call?

Comment: There's a few different login flows so i'm not sure which you're using - if you're logging users in 'server side' the call to /access_token should be the second part of the process, with the first being to redirect the user to  `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?` with a response_type of `code`, then you use  the code in your call to the /access_token endpoint to exchange the code for a token - if so, it's the call to /dialog/oauth which needs you to specify `auth_type:rerequest`